# XML Parse Server Issue

Tags: php, xml, laravel, guzzle

I have two servers both using the Guzzle package in my laravel application.

When I call to my endpoint one server returns the correct XML. But the other server insists of returning odd numbers right before (and at the end) of the XML causing errors on parse.

```
00006000
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    ........ 
</SurveyDefinition>

00000000
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue with this but with an endpoint returning JSON.

Installing `php-curl` module fixed the problem (based on this ticket on Guzzle's repo)

https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1385